# Exportar valores de um array php em um .csv, inserindo cada valor em uma célula

Tags: php, csv

Estou tentando criar uma função que armazene os valores de um array em um arquivo .csv, porém dentro do .csv é armazenado apenas o nível do array pai, por exemplo:  `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`.
O código da função:

```
function convert_data_to_csv( $data ) {
    $content = array();
    foreach ( $data as $array ) {
        foreach ( $array as $row ) {
            $content .= $row;
            file_put_contents( 'http://127.0.0.1/proj/src/csv/certificados.csv', $content );
        }
    }
}
```

Os dados do array passado como parâmetro da função são:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["fruta"]=>
      string(6) "banana"
      ["cor"]=>
      string(4) "azul"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["fruta"]=>
      string(4) "maçã"
      ["cor"]=>
      string(5) "verde"
    }
  }
```

Como posso modificar o código da função para retornar o .csv com cada valor do array em uma célula? Como nesse exemplo:

```
banana,azul
maçã,verde
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso vai funcionar, acredito seja questão de colocar mais um `foreach` no seu `array` tem 3 níveis.

```
function convert_data_to_csv( $data ) {
    $content = array();
    foreach ( $data as $array ) {
        foreach ( $array as $row ) {
            foreach ( $row as $novarow ) {
                $content .= $novarow.';';
                file_put_contents( 'http://127.0.0.1/proj/src/csv/certificados.csv', $content );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Nos meus códigos eu costumo usar essa função para gerar meus csvs e afins a partir de arrays.

```
function array_para_csv(array &$array){
       
        // Formatação Coluna;
        $header = '';
        $content = '';

        $flag = false;
    
        foreach($array as $row) {
        
            if(!$flag) {
              // display field/column names as first row
              $header .= implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
              $flag = true;
            }
            $content .= implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
        }

        return $header.$content;


    }

function cabecalho_download_csv($filename) {
        
        // desabilitar cache
        $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
        header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
        header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

        // forçar download
        // header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
        // header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');  
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");

        // disposição do texto / codificação
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    }

cabecalho_download_csv("lista_cadastro_".date("YmdHis") . ".csv");
        echo array_para_csv($array);
        exit();
```

Porém o array tem que ser passado em um estrutura especifica como abaixo, onde a chave se torna o nome da coluna:

```
$frutas[1] = 'banana';
$frutas[2] = 'maçã';
```

Comment: Coloquei mais um foreach no array, mas retorna o csv com os dados na mesma célula: ```bananaazulmaçãverde```

Comment: Se você concatenar um ; no retorno não resolve, veja como coloquei no código editado.